# Button going through all if statements on 1 button press - objective C

Tags: objective-c, button, if-statement, uibutton, ibaction

My apologies if this is a simple thing to do, i am still new to objective C.
I have a button which I am trying to change the image and text of each time it is pressed, but my issue is that it is going through every if in one go till the end of the IBAction.
What do I need to do for it to only do 1 "if" per click of the button?
Thanks

```
-(IBAction)Button1:(UIButton *)sender {
if (button1TapCount == 0) {
    button1TapCount = 1;
    textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed");
    button1ImageName  = (@"test.png");
    [self buttonschange];
}
if (button1TapCount == 1) {
    button1TapCount = 2;
    textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed twice");
    button1ImageName  = (@"test1.png");
    [self buttonschange];
}
if (button1TapCount == 2) {
    button1TapCount = 3;
    textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed third time");
    button1ImageName  = (@"test2.png");
    [self buttonschange];
}
}
```

Comment: Well, in the first if clause you set tap count to 1, then test for 1 in the second if.  Dude, there's this thing called `else`.

Comment: And please -- quite with the Objective-C right now and go back and learn C first.  None of the Objective-C tutorials or texts teach you the basics of C that you need -- they assume you already know it.

Comment: i knew it would be obvious @HotLicks, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you aren't using `else` and you are changing `button1TapCount` in each `if` statement so that the *next* `if` resolves it to be true.

Use:

```
if (button1TapCount == 0) {
    button1TapCount = 1;
    textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed");
    button1ImageName  = (@"test.png");
    [self buttonschange];
} else if (button1TapCount == 1) {
    button1TapCount = 2;
    textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed twice");
    button1ImageName  = (@"test1.png");
    [self buttonschange];
} else if (button1TapCount == 2) {
    button1TapCount = 3;
    textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed third time");
    button1ImageName  = (@"test2.png");
    [self buttonschange];
}
```

Comment: i completely forgot about using Else, very obvious, apologies!

Comment: @Manesh Using `switch` is better still.

Answer (score 0):

In the first if you're setting button1TapCount to 1, so the second if is true as well. I think what you need is else if:

```
-(IBAction)Button1:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (button1TapCount == 0) {
        button1TapCount = 1;
        textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed");
        button1ImageName  = (@"test.png");
        [self buttonschange];
    }
    else if (button1TapCount == 1) {
        button1TapCount = 2;
        textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed twice");
        button1ImageName  = (@"test1.png");
        [self buttonschange];
    }
    else if (button1TapCount == 2) {
        button1TapCount = 3;
        textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed third time");
        button1ImageName  = (@"test2.png");
        [self buttonschange];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use **if-else** or **return** or **switch**

```
-(IBAction)Button1:(UIButton *)sender {
if (button1TapCount == 0) {
    button1TapCount = 1;
    textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed");
    button1ImageName  = (@"test.png");
    [self buttonschange];
return;
}
if (button1TapCount == 1) {
    button1TapCount = 2;
    textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed twice");
    button1ImageName  = (@"test1.png");
    [self buttonschange];
return;
}
if (button1TapCount == 2) {
    button1TapCount = 3;
    textString = (@"Button 1 Pressed third time");
    button1ImageName  = (@"test2.png");
    [self buttonschange];
return;

}
}
```

Comment: hmm... but I just gave third option, apart from switch.

Comment: Should have gone with `switch` then.  It's actually the best answer :)